# Python and SQlite interaction how to remove the U?

Tags: python, sqlite

Evening, i use the following code to retrieve data from the database in order to edit

```
os.system('cls')
    print("Editing the details")
    conn = sqlite3.connect('SADS.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print " "
    choice = raw_input("Does the Customer know their user ID? Y/N : ")
    if choice == "N":
        number = raw_input("What is their phone number? : ")
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")
        while True:
            rows = cur.fetchone()
            if rows == None:
                print "No one found with that record"
                break
            print rows
    raw_input("Press Enter to return to the menu")
    os.system('cls')
```

But when i do it i am returned with the following result :

```
(u'0001', u'Stack', u'Overflow', u'Confused', u'', u'sqlite', u'PYTH OON', u'07831994131', u'TEST@hotmail.com')
```

Oh p.s those arent the real details i edited them for my safety :')

But anyway, how do i remove the u's before each piece of data?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to? It just specifies the encoding of the results.

Comment: the u just means that it's unicode data. You should print it out in a different format if you don't want it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `u` just means that you have a Unicode string, and is not part of the string contents.

The `u` gets output because you printed the entire tuple *as a tuple*, not the individual strings.

The following code works just fine:

```
print "Name: %s %s, phone: %s" % (rows[1], rows[2], rows[7])
```

Comment: It will crash if row contains non-ASCII characters

Comment: If the application writes non-ASCII Unicode characters to the database, then of course it has to handle the results as Unicode.

Comment: Yes, but I think you should do print u"Name: %s %s, phone: %s" % (rows[1], rows[2], rows[7]) or  u"Name: %s %s, phone: %s" % (rows[1].encode("utf-8"), rows[2].encode("utf-8"), rows[7].encode("utf-8"))